# Insert value into Pandas Dataframe as part of an iteration loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a script to test a couple of my Azure OpenAI prompts. I've created a pandas dataframe from a CSV file that has my prompts, i'm iterating through it and I send the prompt to the openAI endpoint in this loop.

However, as part of this task, I wanted to save each response and add it back to an already existing column of my dataframe, a column called AI response.

Here is the only dataframe I want to use and how it is originally loaded from my csv:

```
   Description   Chat  AI Response  
0  Zero          Yes      NaN   
1  One           Yes      NaN   
2  Two           Yes      NaN   
3  Three         Yes      NaN
```

Here is the code where I am trying to do this:

```
for index, row in df_descriptions.iterrows():
    prompt = row['description']
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        engine="gpt-35-turbo",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are an AI assistant"},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        ],
        temperature=0.3,
        max_tokens=1000,
        top_p=0.95,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0,
        stop=None,
    )
    df_descriptions.insert(2, 'AI Response', response.choices[0].message.content)
    print(df_descriptions['AI Response'])
    time.sleep(5)
```

This code just errors out with the AI response column already exists, which makes sense, but what I am trying to get is

On 1st iteration of the loop, add the response that we got from the enpoint to the AI response column of the dataframe:

```
   Description   Chat  AI Response  
0  Zero          Yes      Answer 1   
1  One           Yes      NaN   
2  Two           Yes      NaN   
3  Three         Yes      NaN
```

On 2nd iteration of the loop, add the response to the second row of my dataframe:

```
   Description   Chat  AI Response  
0  Zero          Yes      Answer 0   
1  One           Yes      Answer 1  
2  Two           Yes      NaN   
3  Three         Yes      NaN
```

And so on.

I looked through the loc class but I think I would have to index the whole DF first, which I just think it's inefficient.

Any ideas would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to create a sample and I'll edit the OP. Unfortunately this uses data that I can't share so I'll try my best to create something readable

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe will already have an index, and you can use `.loc` like this, at the end of the loop:

```
for index, row in df_descriptions.iterrows():
    [your stuff here...]
    # save response to the dataframe
    df_descriptions.loc[index, "AI Response"] = response.choices[0].message.content
```